# Подключение меню из php-файла

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, меню

Визуальная настройка меню из админки WP, конечно, проста и удобна. Но создавать его с нуля, когда оно уже есть в виде кода, лень. Как подключить/вставить собственное уже готовое меню из имеющегося php-файла?

Comment: [get_template_part()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part)

Comment: Пробовал <?php get_template_part( 'main-menu' ); ?>, не сработало

Comment: Где у Вас этот файл `main-menu` лежит?

Comment: В папке темы, рядом с прочими шаблонами. Пробовал также перемещать его в подпапку parts и переименовывать в main-nav на случай, если на menu система вдруг реагирует. Даже попытался добавить в чистый html-код внутри файла <?php ?>. Без результата

Comment: 1. Что тогда внутри файла `main-menu.php`? 2. `если на menu система вдруг реагирует` -- реагирует в каком смысле? 3. `Даже попытался добавить в чистый html-код внутри файла <?php ?>` -- я предполагал что у Вас и так чистый HTML код внутри файла. Потому как тогда не совсем ясно, что Вам "лень" создавать с нуля.

Comment: В main-menu чистый html: div... ul... li... Просто подумал, вдруг из-за слага-menu что-то может не сработать. Или, может, в html-код на всякий случай добавить php... В общем, испробовал все возможные варианты запустить меню извне. Когда уже полностью построен список меню кодом, создавать его заново из визуальных кирпичиков видится пустой и лишней работой

Comment: >"Когда уже полностью построен список меню кодом, создавать его заново из визуальных кирпичиков видится пустой и лишней работой"... 1. Собрать даже сложное меню в админке - мин 10-15 макс. У тебя уже прошли сутки, а задача всё ещё не решена. 2. Со временем гемороя с твоим "решением" добавится и ты всё равно переделаешь на нормальную структуру.

Comment: Нашел ошибку сам: в сдвоенном названии файла, который надо передавать как get_template_part ( 'main', 'menu' ); Спасибо Simon за поддержку. Спасибо СеВладу за страну советов